# Avoid binding of child view to right corner if left view is large

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to manage items below main text in next way.
if we have a lot of place, "RIGHT" text should be aligned to right of left text. If we have no place, "RIGHT" text should be at right of parent and left text should be elipsized. Right text should not be at the right corner if we have a lot of place.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="25dp"
    android:paddingStart="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/event_item_bg">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iv_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_more"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is some title text. Can be long. And take several lines"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_status"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:text="This text can be long too. In should not shift view at right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_more"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="LIVE"

        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: put two textviews inside `horizontal linearlayout` and make the LIVE textview width as `match_parent`

Comment: @JyotiJK I had tried this. It works for large view, but it shifts text "LIVE" for small view out of borders of parrent

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved your issue refer below codes:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_status"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    tools:text="This text can be long too. In should not shift view at rights"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    tools:text="LIVE" />
```

**Updated code:**

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_status"
    tools:text="This text can be long too. In should not shift view at rights" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_status"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
    tools:text="LIVE" />
```

Comment: It works for a large screen. But when screen small, the RIGHT text is shifted out of borders of parent and not visible. But I need to have it at right of parrent. Thanks.

Comment: @ДмитроЯковлєв , Please try my updated code, I hope it will work for you.

Comment: This works fine for SMALL, but for a large screen, this text is aligned to the right of the parent. (http://joxi.ru/V2VgGjXs0yPWeA) But I am trying to make it aligned to left text for large screen, and aligned to right for a small screen.

Comment: @ДмитроЯковлєв, You can use `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1.0"` for large text and `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.5"` for "LIVE" text

Comment: I had tried your proposition. It works fine for a large screen. But it works not ideal for small (http://joxi.ru/a2XG7vkty8BODm). The "LIVE" text should be at the right of a parent in an ideal case.

Comment: @ДмитроЯковлєв, It's small issue but you have to try up to not getting correct. Now I have try with this `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` add in both views and check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168124/discussion-between-immodi-and--).

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try it by nesting another layout that has flexible children 
placement like the RelativeLayout
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="25dp"
    android:paddingStart="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/event_item_bg">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iv_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_more"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is some title text. Can be long. And take 
    several lines"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#9b9b9b"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="This text can be long too. In "/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="LIVE" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: It works fine for large screen. I had used similar before. But it does not works for small screen. When left text is too long and view is small, so the "LIVE" text will be shifted and not visible.